# What are requirements to use CouchDB on Android?

Tags: android, couchdb

I'd like to know the requirements to use [CouchDB on Android](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-mobile-for-android/current). I've found an [example application](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase) and the [MobileFuton](https://github.com/daleharvey/Android-MobileFuton).

Can CouchDB be used without having an external storage and is it usable on low-end devices as it is said to have a large memory and storage footprint?

*Please note the related [CouchDB Forum Thread](http://www.couchbase.org/forums/thread/couchdb-android-device)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External storage (an SD card) is required for Couchbase for Android.  I missed this and didn't have one configured on my emulator.  Took me a bit to figure out that was the problem.

My application is big (for mobile standards).  It weighs in at 15 Mb.  I am using Ektorp (CouchDB JPA like abstraction) which has several dependencies, one which requires a separate Apache HttpClient version (used "jarjar links" to prevent conflicts with the Android shipped HttpClient version). The EmptyApp available from the link below weighs in at 10 Mb.

If size isn't a requirement, I'd recommend it.  Development was an absolute dream.

This is the best tutorial I found on setting it up:
http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Android